# How to use the same value multiple times in jdbc postgresql prepared statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Is there a way to use the same variable numerous times in a prepared statement with the jdbc postgresql driver?

For example I want to use the following statement but have the same value for each question mark:

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
    pg.prepareCall("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1=? AND col2=? AND col3=?");
```

but instead of entering the code three times, such as:

```
ps.setInt(0,1);
ps.setInt(1,1);
ps.setInt(2,1);
```

is there a way to simply use the same value in each of the variables?  I'm think of something similar to the usage in [pypostgresql](http://python.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/1.0/driver.html#parameterized-statements) where one can simply say `$1` for use with each of the fields.

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1=$1 AND col2=$1 AND col3=$1"
```

Comment: This topic was already discussed [here][1]. Duplicated?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673599/jdbc-preparedstatement-using-the-same-argument-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, plain JDBC does not support named query parameters. You might make a small function to put the value in all of the places. Otherwise you are looking at using something heavier like Spring or JPA.