# Utilise the same parameter multiple times in WHERE conditions of an SQL query for use in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

To my Oracle DB I want to send via JDBC and a prepared statement SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = <ONEVAL> col2 = <ONEVAL> AND col3 = <ONEVAL>;
```

I know from SO answer [How to use the same value multiple times in jdbc postgresql prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483889/how-to-use-the-same-value-multiple-times-in-jdbc-postgresql-prepared-statement) that JDBC doesn't support named parameters, so a direct prepared statement

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?;
```

only works if I provide `<ONEVAL>` 3 times, but I do not want to do that, I rather would like to adjust the SQL of the prepared statement, so that it takes only one `?` but applies it to all `WHERE` conditions. Something like

```
WITH VAl = ? SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = VAL AND col2 = VAL AND col3 = VAL;
```

But *this try doesn't seem to work*. Is there way to do this kind of multi-use of *one* prepared statement parameter in the SQL string?

#### Other things I have tried:

After the kind suggestion by @Selvin I used the following SQL string for the prepared statement:

```
DECLARE val varchar(30) :=? ; SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1=&val AND col2=&val AND col3=&val
```

Then I get the error "*ORA-06550: line 1, column 33: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:* [...]"

Comment: How could `col1` be two values at the same time? And sure, define a PL/SQL stored procedure and invoke that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ups, this was a typo! Should read the second time `col2`. Corrected the question. Thanks for spotting this!

Comment: I assume that's just a typo for `col2`, that said you can technically wrap the functionality of PreparedStatement with your own class that does support named parameters. Just make sure it swaps the named parameters to `?` and calls `#set*` accordingly. Don't swap the variables in yourself, because then why prepare anyhow.

Comment: I don't get it... Answers for other similar questions are jdbc doesn't support it and you are still asking

Comment: @Selvin Not at all. I would like the SLQ string to do the duplication work and keep the Java part as brief at possible (so that I can swap out the SQL string at a later state without much change to the Java code).

Comment: Anyway did you tried `DECLARE val varchar(20) :=? ; select... col=&val... ;` then us

Comment: @Selvin Haven't tried that, but looks promising! :-) Will try it and report back.

Comment: @Selvin This doesn't seem to work either. See added last section of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got it right, you need all three columns to be equal to the same value at the same time, so my guess is that these SQL will help you

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = ? AND col1 = col2 AND col1 = col3;
```

UPD: There is a better or I'd say more compact idea

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ? = all(col1, col2, col3)
```

Comment: Cool solution! Not the way I had envisioned, but certainly working in my case. Particularly the use of `ALL` is nifty. Thanks heaps!