# Catch-all value for a parameter in the WHERE clause of a Prepared Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, oracle18c

I have the following Prepared Statement which I send via the JDBC driver to an Oracle database:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ? = ANY(col1, col2)
```

Now, normally when I execute this as a query I provide a value which exists in `col1` or `col2` and Oracle dutifully returns all rows containing the value.

However I would like to use the same prepared statement to fetch ***all*** rows in the table by providing something like a wildcard parameter. I tried Strings like "*" and "" but it always returns *no* rows.

Does a value for the parameter in this prepared statement exist with which I fetch *all* rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
where nvl(?, col1) in (col1, col2)
```

and pass a `null` in if you want all values.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted. Thanks a  lot.

Answer (score 0):

You would often use `NULL` for this purpose.  Something like this:

```
WHERE ? IN (col1, col2) OR ? IS NULL
```

Comment: Interesting idea, however with your statement I see the problem that I always have to provide **2** values to it - just for the rare extra case of a full listing. (For the discussion of multiple "?" see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014309/utilise-the-same-parameter-multiple-times-in-where-conditions-of-an-sql-query-fo/67015608#67015608).)

Comment: @halloleo . . . I would recommend that you use a named parameter, so it is like `where :param in (col1, col2) or :param is null`.

Comment: Does the JDBC driver support named parameters in Prepared Statements? From [what I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483965/65889), not.